# Allure: Jenkins plugin and Maven report generation

Tags: maven, jenkins, testng, allure

I'm using **Jenkins** with [Allure Jenkins plugin](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-jenkins-plugin) and I'm trying to generate Allure reports for my Maven project. Unfortunately I'm getting the following error:

```
    Allure Report Generation: started
    Allure Report Generation: find directories by mask [**/allure-results]
    Allure Report Generation: found allure result directories [/home/chetan/.jenkins/jobs/mlmk/workspace/target/allure-results]
    Allure Report Generation: copy founded directories in directory [/home/chetan/.jenkins/jobs/mlmk/workspace/allure7650093845080999575.tmp/results]
    Allure Report Generation: generate report from directory [/home/chetan/.jenkins/jobs/mlmk/workspace/allure7650093845080999575.tmp]
    ERROR: Publisher ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.AllureReportPublisher aborted due to exception
    java.io.IOException: ru.yandex.qatools.allure.report.AllureReportBuilderException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.utils.ReportGenerator.invoke(ReportGenerator.java:47)
        at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.utils.ReportGenerator.invoke(ReportGenerator.java:18)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:922)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:895)
        at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.AllureReportPublisher.generateReport(AllureReportPublisher.java:193)
        at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.AllureReportPublisher.perform(AllureReportPublisher.java:135)
        at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$2.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:32)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:772)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:736)
        at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:685)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1757)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234)
    Caused by: ru.yandex.qatools.allure.report.AllureReportBuilderException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.report.AllureReportBuilder.processResults(AllureReportBuilder.java:135)
        at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.utils.ReportGenerator.invoke(ReportGenerator.java:44)
        ... 14 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.report.AllureReportBuilder.processResults(AllureReportBuilder.java:133)
        ... 15 more
    Caused by: ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.ReportGenerationException: net.sf.saxon.event.NoOpenStartTagException: An attribute node (version) cannot be created after the children of the containing element
        at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.utils.XslTransformationUtils.applyTransformation(XslTransformationUtils.java:55)
        at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.utils.XslTransformationUtils.applyTransformation(XslTransformationUtils.java:44)
        at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.utils.XslTransformationUtils.applyTransformation(XslTransformationUtils.java:35)
        at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.utils.XslTransformationUtils.applyTransformations(XslTransformationUtils.java:29)
        at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.TestSuiteFiles.generateTestRun(TestSuiteFiles.java:50)
        at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.AllureReportGenerator.generate(AllureReportGenerator.java:39)
        ... 20 more
    Caused by: net.sf.saxon.event.NoOpenStartTagException: An attribute node (version) cannot be created after the children of the containing element
        at net.sf.saxon.event.NoOpenStartTagException.makeNoOpenStartTagException(NoOpenStartTagException.java:49)
        at net.sf.saxon.event.ComplexContentOutputter.attribute(ComplexContentOutputter.java:296)
        at net.sf.saxon.instruct.CopyOf.copyAttribute(CopyOf.java:572)
        at net.sf.saxon.instruct.Copy.processLeavingTail(Copy.java:221)
        at net.sf.saxon.instruct.Template.expand(Template.java:220)
        at net.sf.saxon.instruct.CallTemplate$CallTemplatePackage.processLeavingTail(CallTemplate.java:440)
        at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ApplyTemplates.applyTemplates(ApplyTemplates.java:317)
        at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ApplyTemplates.apply(ApplyTemplates.java:210)
        at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ApplyTemplates.processLeavingTail(ApplyTemplates.java:174)
        at net.sf.saxon.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:556)
        at net.sf.saxon.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:93)
        at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:296)
        at net.sf.saxon.instruct.Template.applyLeavingTail(Template.java:203)
        at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ApplyTemplates.applyTemplates(ApplyTemplates.java:345)
        at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ApplyTemplates.apply(ApplyTemplates.java:210)
        at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ApplyTemplates.process(ApplyTemplates.java:170)
        at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:296)
        at net.sf.saxon.instruct.Copy.processLeavingTail(Copy.java:217)
        at net.sf.saxon.instruct.Template.expand(Template.java:220)
        at net.sf.saxon.instruct.CallTemplate$CallTemplatePackage.processLeavingTail(CallTemplate.java:440)
        at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ApplyTemplates.applyTemplates(ApplyTemplates.java:317)
        at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ApplyTemplates.apply(ApplyTemplates.java:210)
        at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ApplyTemplates.processLeavingTail(ApplyTemplates.java:174)
        at net.sf.saxon.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:556)
        at net.sf.saxon.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:93)
        at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:296)
        at net.sf.saxon.instruct.Template.applyLeavingTail(Template.java:203)
        at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ApplyTemplates.applyTemplates(ApplyTemplates.java:345)
        at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ApplyTemplates.defaultAction(ApplyTemplates.java:378)
        at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ApplyTemplates.applyTemplates(ApplyTemplates.java:333)
        at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transformDocument(Controller.java:1807)
        at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transform(Controller.java:1621)
        at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.utils.XslTransformationUtils.applyTransformation(XslTransformationUtils.java:52)
        ... 25 more
    Finished: FAILURE
```

Where is the problem here? Could someone provide a pom example for Allure reporting with TestNg?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of Allure being used with TestNG: **https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-testng-example**. Btw, your issue may be related to the fact that Jenkins plugin downloads all required dependencies from the Internet. It you're using proxies this can be the reason why it's not working (here's the issue: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-report-builder/issues/3).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error looks like a problem with XML processing at the moment of actual report generation.
If you could show the generated .xml report files and post them here (at least a part) we could try to see what's wrong with them.

Comment: Yep, XSLT issues are mainly related to XML incompatibility. When using latest version of TestNG adapter - simply try Allure version 1.4.0 in Jenkins plugin settings.